Troubleshooting MLflow Artifact Logging with ZenML
I am currently working on an MLOps project using ZenML and MLflow, and I have encountered an issue that I can't seem to resolve. I new in the mlops field and am reaching out for help and advice. Here’s a detailed overview of the problem I’m facing.
Tools and Technologies:
ZenML, MLflow, PyTorch
Environment:
Operating System: Windows
Python Version: 3.11
ZenML Version: 0.58.0
MLflow Version: 2.12.2
Torch Version: 2.2.0
MLflow and ZenML Configuration
I have set up my ZenML stack with the following components:
Artifact Store: local_store
Model Deployer: mlflow_deployer
Orchestrator: local_orchestrator
Experiment Tracker: mlflow_tracker
Issue Description:
Despite following all the setup steps and ensuring that the configurations are correct, I am encountering an issue where the artifacts (such as model files) are not being logged correctly in the mlruns directory. Only the model folder gets created, but the expected files within the run ID and artifacts folders are missing.
I would really appreciate your help.
reading documentation and googling.

Can you add in the question the code that you use to make the logging of the artifacts happen? In general in order to log artifacts you will need to have lines of code that take care of that.
